# Como puedo actualizar y eliminar datos de una tabla de muchos a muchos en Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

escribo en esta oportunidad porque tengo una duda, como puedo actualizar una tabla que es el resultado de la relación muchos a muchos, lo estaba haciendo así pero creo que esta muy malo porque no me funciona.

```
  pagoConcepto = context.ConceptoPagos.Where(x => x.conceptoId == conceptoID).ToList();
                        pagoConcepto.ConceptoPagoRols.Clear();

                        var pagoRole = roles;
                        if (pagoRole != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in pagoRole)
                            {
                                ConceptoPagoRol rol = new ConceptoPagoRol()
                                {
                                    rolID = Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString()),
                                    conceptoId = conceptoID,
                                    Cr_created_at = DateTime.Now,
                                    Cr_updated_at = DateTime.Now
                                };
                                context.ConceptoPagoRols.Add(rol);
                            }
                        }
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione un rol si lo agrego fino pero cuando lo edito, es decir, que lo elimine de la lista del concepto lo pueda eliminar de la tabla pero noc como podria hacerlo.

Que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: que version de EF concretamente estas utilizando? porque el mapping mucho a mucho de EF6 es muy diferente a EF Core

Comment: Saludos, estoy utilizando la EF Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que no funciona porque te esta faltando la linea

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

sin esta no va a ejecutar las operaciones contra la db, solo quedara en memoria la asignacion

Veo que esta la tabla intermedia `ConceptoPagoRol`, pero esto difiere si es `entity framework 6` a `entity framework core`, es muy distinto.

En EF6 la tabla intermedia no se asocia a una entidad, por lo tanto `ConceptoPagoRol` no deberia estar. Ahora si es EF Core en este caso si debes declarar la tabla intermedia asociandola a una tabla, seria correcto tener `ConceptoPagoRol`

Para eliminar simplemente deberias quitar la entidad de la coleccion

[Configuring Many To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)

[Relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Si analiza los ejemplos de github donde publique sobre este tema en un evento

[EntityFrameworkCoreMappings](https://github.com/ltuttini/EntityFrameworkCoreMappings)

veras que se puede eliminar indicnado las keys intervinientes en la relacion

```
ConceptoPagoRol rol = new ConceptoPagoRol()
{
  rolID = Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString()),
  conceptoId = conceptoID,
};
context.Remove(rol);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Gracias por responderme, voy a revisar los link que colocaste, estoy utilizando la versión EF Core, de esta manera me gusta porque asi elimino una especifica, hay algo que me ha dado mucha curiosidad en la tabla ConceptoPagoRol se me creo una columna llamada "ConceptoPagoconceptoId" pero esta siempre se guarda en null pero en mi modelo no la defini, a que se puede deber? es normal que se cree columna asi?

Comment: Esa columna no deberia ser necesaria, no se quien la genero pero se supone que la tabla ConceptoPagoRol deberia tener una key compuesta con rolID y conceptoId, podrias ver de quitar esa propiedad y su mapping

Comment: ok, voy a chequear eso, muchas gracias